# Reduce the spacing between letters in the text function

Tags: r

I am trying to find a way to reduce the space between letters in a plot when i use the text function...

```
par(mar=rep(0,4))
plot.new()
text(0.5,0.8,"text", cex=8)
```

I want to have almost no space between each letters, or the option for overlapping (as in the bottom of the plot below...I did this by hand in MS paint).

[image: text]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a start to a function to do this:

```
   squishtext <- function(x,y, text, squish=1) {
        text <- strsplit(text, '')[[1]]
        w <- strwidth(text)
        ww <- cumsum(c(0,head(w,-1)) * squish)
        text( x + ww, y, text, adj=c(0,0) )
    }
```

and a quick example/check:

```
    plot(1:10, type='n')
    text( 5, 3, "test", adj=c(0,0) )
    squishtext( 5, 4, "test", squish=1 )
    squishtext( 5, 5, "test", squish=0.8 )
    squishtext( 5, 6, "test", squish=0.5 )
    squishtext( 5, 7, "test", squish=1.2 )
    squishtext( 5, 8, "test", squish=2 )
```

It could be expanded to take additional parameters (`adj`, `cex`, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

One option:

```
par(mar=rep(0,4))
plot.new()

word = "text"
letters = strsplit(word,"")

xstart = .4
ystart = .8
space = .075

for(i in 1:length(letters[[1]])){

    text(xstart,ystart,letters[[1]][i], cex=8)
    xstart = xstart + space

}
```

Although me personally, I would do it manually one letter at a time like this:

```
par(mar=rep(0,4))
plot.new()

text(.5,.8,"t", cex=8)
text(.57,.8,"e", cex=8)
text(.645,.8,"x", cex=8)
text(.7,.8,"t", cex=8)
```